# How to continue a title if that section bleeds to another page in google docs using app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am working with a google docs file with already populated sections and their section headers. I read the file and replace some text.The issue is depending on the size of the text I replace the section content might move to the other page.In that case I want the section title to re-appear at the start of the next page.

For a example :
The first page section title is - Global History

And if that section goes to the other page the title should be - Global History(Cont.)

The main issue I am having is that I can't find the end of a page. I tried using page break

```
  var paras = editBody.getParagraphs()
  for(i=0;i<paras.length;i++){
    if (paras[i].findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK) != null) {
      Logger.log('page break')
    }
  }
```

But this did not work, even though my document already has 5 pages it returned without a single page break.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the end of a page in a Google document it's quite complex as the Google Apps Scirpt Documents Service and the Google Docs API hasn't a method for this, so you should calculate the end of page considering the page margins, line spacing, font sizes, etc.

A simpler approach might be to estimate how many pages will require each section and set the continuation section title in advance, setting these titles with the "Add page break before" option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Regarding the simpler approach, how can one estimate how many pages each section take ? because the content I replace are dynamic and can have any number of characters